# OpenWRT not connecting WAN port through 25ft Cat-something run

Tags: openwrt

We have been having random wifi drops outs on our stock firmware Linksys EA4500 since our family have been sheltering in place and all working at home during the week, so I thought it a good opportunity to get more exposure to 3rd party firmware and confirm or not that it is the stock firmware that is causing the lockups/reboots.

So I start out this morning backing up current config and downloading both stock firmware (just in case, even though I know that my router has a backup partition) and the only 3rd party firmware that seemed to be compatible with my router - OpenWRT. After uploading the firmware, restarting, and going through the options to get wifi and DHCP setup, I notice that the WAN port has no lights, nor an Rx/IP. MANY web searches later, I had tried putting IP from stock firmware into static WAN IP settings; tried executing "ipconfig /release" from my Window's PC that could get internet with the cable from the ONT plugged into it, then waiting 2 hours to try restarting the router and the WAN interface (with DHCP client changed back to be the protocol); ticking "Use broadcast flag"; unplugging router and giving it 2 hours before plugging it back in; and a few more things I now forget, all to absolutely no sign of life from the WAN port lights or WAN Rx in the OpenWRT interface.

To my utter annoyance I found that on a hunch plugging a 1ft cable between the ONT and the router (Stock firmware works most of the time with a 25ft cat-something run) got the WAN lights working, and an IP, and internet!

Why does my laptop or the stock firmware of this router work through this 25ft cat-something run, and not the blinking OpenWRT firmware?? Is there logs beyond Status -> System Log to explore what udhcpc is doing in between the below log entries that may explain the reason for a possible non-successful low level connection not allowing the higher level assignment of an IP?

```
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is enabled
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan6' is enabled
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: bridge 'br-lan' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' has link connectivity
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: VLAN 'eth0.1' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'lo' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'loopback' has link connectivity
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth1' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: VLAN 'eth1.2' link is up
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' has link connectivity
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is setting up now
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan6' has link connectivity
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan6' is setting up now
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S96led: setting up led health
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S96led: setting up led pulse
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.notice netifd: wan (1335): udhcpc: started, v1.30.1
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 user.notice firewall: Reloading firewall due to ifup of lan (br-lan)
Wed Jan 29 16:20:12 2020 daemon.err odhcp6c[1339]: Failed to send RS (Address not available)
Wed Jan 29 16:20:13 2020 kern.info kernel: [   16.241603] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Wed Jan 29 16:20:13 2020 kern.info kernel: [   16.248480] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-lan: link becomes ready
Wed Jan 29 16:20:13 2020 kern.info kernel: [   16.255141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1:link becomes ready
Wed Jan 29 16:20:13 2020 daemon.notice netifd: wan (1335): udhcpc: sending discover
```

Comment: *maybe* it didn't detect some degradation (or broken cable) and didn't switch to a different negociated (or not) speed. It could have  chosen 1000Tx (requires cat 6 using 2 pairs) instead of 1000T (requires cat 5e using 4 pairs), or didn't downgrade to 100Tx. Try and check with `ethtool` or else with `mii-tool`. Also search for Q/A using those commands to force a speed. But everything is more complicated if your hardware is using DSA/switchdev, where the interface you see isn't always the actual interface negociating.

Comment: There's also the possibility that it's not the OS difference, but something else you do to the 25ft run while switching OS that sometimes causes it to work, and sometimes not. Do you have an Ethernet cable tester, or can you borrow one?

Comment: Thanks @A.B! Will look into how to use those tools to get more info about what is happening at the speed negotiating level.

Comment: @dirkt Alas I don't have an Ethernet cable tester available to me. In some tests I didn't touch the cable at all when I changed between stock and 3rd party firmware, and having 2/3 devices working seemingly no matter how the cable is flexed coming through the wall makes this possibility remote to my mind. Think it is likely a speed negotiation/overall cable quality issue which I will pursue with the tools that A.D. suggested, but thanks for commenting!